# Como fazer requisição HTTP?

Tags: node.js, http-request

Gostaria de fazer uma requisição HTTP para o servidor da minha faculdade imitando as requisições enviadas pelo navegador para que eu possa me logar e verificar minhas notas.

Já tenho experiência com desenvolvimento mobile, a minha intenção é futuramente desenvolver um App para acesso de notas, faltas, matérias da faculdade.

Como posso fazer essas requisições em Node.js?

Comment: Cara verifica se eles tem uma API para programadores usarem (geralmente não tem), ou tenta usar o CURL, [da uma olhada nesse tutorial](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/tutorial-basico-de-curl-instalacao-configuracao-e-uso/)

Comment: @JonatanRibeirodosSantos , isso realmente parece ser o que procuro, porem nao tenho conhecimento de php. para rodar um php eu preciso ter um servidor rodando localmente ?

Comment: Amigo qual linguagem você está usando?

Comment: conheco muito bem python e javascript...

Comment: Se quiser usar java, procure a classe `java.net.HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Cara, se tu manja de javascript tenta fazer em nodejs, ou se tu manja de Python da uma olhada em como usar o CURL no python, não deve ser o fim do mundo.

Comment: curl pra python nao existe em windows 64 bits

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Fiz uma pequena edição na pergunta para tentar torná-la mais clara. Entretanto, seria melhor especificar em qual linguagem ou plataforma. Coloquei a tag `android` lá por você ter dito que tem alguma experiência em programação mobile. Mas, por favor, edite sua pergunta especificando melhor com qual tecnologia você quer  fazer as requisições. Abraço!

Comment: Python você pode usar o mechanize, por exemplo...

Comment: Vi que a tag foi alterada para `javascript`. Se quiser fazer um script para rodar no navegador muito provavelmente não será possível fazer requisições HTTP para o servidor da sua faculdade, pois a política padrão de segurança impede requisições Ajax entre domínios diferentes. Seria possível fazer isso com Node.js, mas aí envolveria toda a configuração de ambiente. Talvez seja melhor ficar om o Python. Mas, se você pretende futuramente fazer isso no Android, minha sugestão é já fazer isso em Java para facilitar.

Comment: Concordo com o que disse o @utluiz (menos com a parte de que fazer em Java é mais fácil que Node.js + JavaScript, hehehe).

Comment: Um amigo me aconselhou a usar o node js, ja que o que eu quero fazer e como se fosse um data mining, pois estou tentando receber informações de um servidor sem ser pelo navegador... acho que tentarei usar o node, se alguém tiver algum conselho eu agradeço.

Comment: Então, o Node serve perfeitamente pra isso, não roda no navegador. Você pode até usar um browser *headless* (sem interface gráfica) como o phantomjs, aí consegue minar dados até de sites baseados em ajax (que você não conseguiria normalmente).

Comment: @bfavaretto Não que Java seja mais fácil. É mais fácil passar um código Java para Android só porque é Java também (ou quase isso). ;)

Comment: Ah, eu não tinha me dado conta de que tinha Android na jogada. Nesse caso ele vai ter de engolir o Java mesmo (hehehe x 2). @utluiz

Comment: Poder ser feito com [ZombieJs](http://zombie.labnotes.org) que é um framework para testar páginas da web simulando um navegador e o node tem o PhoneGap que cria aplicações hibridas baseadas em HTML5+CSS+JS para o caso que você deseja para app mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem algumas ferramentas pra esse tipo de técnica (chamada Web Scraping). Em JavaScript algumas alternativas são:

- [mechanize-js](https://github.com/srveit/mechanize-js) uma adaptação da famosa biblioteca Mechanize (originalmente disponível em Perl mas que hoje conta com suporte em diversas linguagens como Python, Ruby, JS, etc);
- [Zombie JS](https://github.com/assaf/zombie): um browser sem interface capaz de emular completamente a interação com uma página web, exatamente da mesma forma que ocorreria com um Browser convencional).

Note que construir um aplicativo em cima desse tipo de interação, enquanto possível, não é a estratégia ideal - depender da camada de visualização de um sistema para extrair dados é uma técnica bastante instável e pode quebrar em detrimento das mais simples modificações por parte deste sistema. A melhor opção seria utilizar uma API estável, com versionamento e documentação; mas isso nem sempre é possível.